# If I get a HE fellowship do I still need a PGCert for academic practice or equivalent to become a lecturer?

Tags: united-kingdom, lecturer, lecture-teaching-method

I have a PhD and have been working as a researcher and associate lecturer in a UK University. I want to become a Lecturer. I have the credentials for a higher education (HE) Fellowship and some for a Senior Fellowship. If I manage to get it do I still need a PGCert (postgraduate certificate for teaching in Higher education)? How difficult is to get a HE Fellowship?

Comment: I would be helpful for an international audience to spell out some of your terms.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the role descriptions for a lecturer in the particular university you're interested in, but I believe it's common that a Fellowship of the HEA (or whatever it's called now) is acceptable evidence of teaching qualification in most places.

I don't think either most of the PGCert classes or the HE fellowship application are that demanding. Applying directly to a HE fellowship requires a bit more documented evidence of previous teaching experience and a variety of bits of reflective text, but it's not too onerous, especially if you have someone who's done it before to provide you with some guidance. PGCerts are simpler if you don't have much previous experience.

Our university at least in principle supports either route, although I think the PGCert is heavily favoured, at least in more research-intensive areas where people are doing limited teaching.